# ¿Es seguro usar un cerfificado emitido por la página de Let's encrypt?

Tags: web, seguridad, https, ssl, letsencrypt

Buenas ,
me han hablado de una página llamada Let's encrypt dónde se pueden generar certificados SSL  gratis, ¿es seguro este certificado que se genera?, ya que no se conoce la cadena de confianza que tiene.

Por otra parte, creo que se caduca cada cierto tiempo, ¿es posible volverlo a validar de alguna forma?¿con openssl se podría volver a darle validez?

Muchas gracias, chicos!!!

Comment: Si es seguro.  Al instalarlo tu equipo debe cumplir con al menos tener definido el sitio en tu Apache.
Lo que no te da este servicio es la certificación de empresa y organización. Es decir si tenes el sitio: misitio.com de ABC S.A. Letsencrypt solo dice que mi sitio.com tiene un certificado válido y que será segura la comunicación pero no asegura que ABC S.A. sea una empresa válida o conocida.
Se vence cada 3 meses pero tiene funciones de renovación automática. Si necesitas certificados del tipo wildcard leí que recién pra este año iban a implementarlo. Espero te sirva la info.

Answer (score 1):

Let's Encrypt actualment ya cuenta con soporte en todos los navegadores (por lo que nunca tendrás problemas de que salga "este sitio no es seguro por lalalala")...

Yo lo utilizo en mi VPS de desarrollo sin problemas y a la fecha no me ha creado inconveniente alguno.

Cabe destacar el tema de la duración, expiran cada 90 días, pero hay proyectos en GitHub para cubrir esa área, por lo que te encargas de configurarlos y crearle un cronjob para que se renueve antes de que expire...

En otro campo, si utilizarás un hosting compartido (con cPanel), hay que mencionar que cPanel tiene actualmente el AutoSSL (por decirle de una forma, sería un Let's Encrypt que nació de un pacto entre cPanel y Comodo)... También es gratuito y expira cada 90 días, pero el sistema padre (WHM) se encarga de crear cronjobs para todos los sitios que se hostean, de forma que se renueven siempre sin que el usuario final (los que adquieren los hostings compartidos) no tengan que preocuparse...

Comment: Me interesa el tema de la renovación automática, ya que actualmente lo renuevo manualmente. Puedes proporcionarme algún enlace?

Comment: @Pikoh En la misma web puedes buscar información: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates

Comment: Entrada de la wikipedia: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let's_encrypt

Comment: Gracias @PabloLozano :)